# complex IF statements with multiple variables possibilities

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need help with making some IF/OR/AND statements.

I have a cell (C8) that can be one of fourteen different variables.  Depending on the value for C8 either cells F8, D8, or E8 will be used in three possible equations.

```
        C   D   E   F   G   H
7                           
8                           
9
```

C8 can equal any of the following values

```
0.5,0.55,0.6,0.7,0.75,1,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5
```

Equations needed:

- IF C8 equals any values from  0.6 - 1.5 will then need to solve for (100-(F8-108)*5))+(G8+1))
- IF C8  equals 0.5 will then need to solve for (100-((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1))
- IF C8 equals 0.55 will then need to solve for (100-((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1)

I currently have this equation C8 if values are 0.6 1.5

```
=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,1,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5},C8)))>0),100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1)),"")
```

I think I need an IF/OR statement for two additional Situation

- C8 equals 0.5 to solve for 100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1))
- C8 equals 0.55 to solve for 100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1))

The following is the they type of IF/OR formulas I have tried.

```
=IF(OR(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,1,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5},C8)))>0), 100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1)), OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0.5,C8)))>0)100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)), OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0.55,C8))>0)100-(((E8-102*5)+(G8*1))"")

=IF(OR(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,1,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5},C8)))>0), 100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1)), (ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0.5,C8)))>0)100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)), (ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0.55,C8))>0)100-(((E8-102*5)+(G8*1))"")
```

Comment: why not just have a table with the values on the left and the results on the right and use vlookup?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to search for the values? If the cell can only equal one of the values you shared you can just build your statement around that assumption.

If that assumption is false, this will not work. `[Equation3]` will be called when `C8` equals anything **BUT** `.50 & .55` so `C8` has to have limitations for this to work.

---

`IF(C8 = .50, [Equation1], IF(C8 = .55, [Equation2], [Equation3]))`

Where

```
[Equation1] = (100-((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1))
[Equation2] = (100-((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1)
[Equation3] = (100-(F8-108)*5))+(G8+1))
```

Comment: `=IF(C8=0.5,(100-((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1)),IF(C8=0.55,(100-((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1)),(100-(F8-108)*5))+(G8+1))` works for me

Comment: Thank you so much.  Second question.  If i wanted the cell to be blank when not all values are filled for either C8, D8, E8 or F8 (depending on situation for either 0.5 or 0.55, or 0.6-1.5 would that be an IF(OR) statement?

Comment: If any one of them is empty don't calculate anything?

Comment: I think so.  I think if any of the variables (C8,D8,G8 or C8,E8,G8 or C8,F8,G8)  for any of the equations are missing if the resulting cell will show blank.

Comment: hello.  I was able to construct three separate formulas that work on their own.  How would i string them together with an OR or AND statement?  Second question how do I keep the cell of the calculations until all three options are filled in?Equation for 0.5 =IF(OR(C8=0.5),(100-(((D8-56)*5)+(G8*1))),"")

Equation for 0.55 =IF(OR(C8=0.55),(100-(((E8-102)*5)+(G8*1))),"")

Equation for values 0.6,0.7,0.75,1.0,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5

=IF(OR(C8=0.6,0.7,0.75,1,1.0625,1.125,1.1875,1.25,1.325,1.375,1.4375,1.5),(100-(((F8-108)*5)+(G8*1))),"")